# Angular 8 loose data after refresh page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have isAdmin boolean property which I am checking user logged in as user or admin.
Backend is .net core 2.2, db - Postgre.
Everything works fine but after refresh I lose isAdmin value.
I have conditional show hide dropdown which is available only for admin roles.
How don't lose data after refreshing?
P.S. How to add logic also to my guard for isAdmin property?
My component looks like:

```
 model: any = {};

  constructor(public authService: AuthService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private router: 
   Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  login() {
    this.authService.login(this.model).subscribe(next => {
      this.model.isAdmin = true;
      this.alertify.success('Logged in as Admin')
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error)
    }, () => {
      this.router.navigate(['/projects'])
    })
  }

  loginAsUser() {
    this.authService.loginAsUser(this.model).subscribe(next => {     
      this.model.isAdmin = false;
      this.alertify.success('Logged in as User')
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error)
    }, () => {
      this.router.navigate(['/home'])
    })
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return this.authService.loggedIn();
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.alertify.message('logged out');
    this.router.navigate(['/home'])
  }
```

My html looks like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/home']">
      <img [src]="iteraLogo" alt="Itera">
    </a>

    <div *ngIf="loggedIn()" class="dropdown" dropdown [hidden]="!model.isAdmin">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" dropdownToggle>
        <strong class="text-primary">Admin Panel</strong>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu mt-4" *dropdownMenu>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/projects']">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/hypervisors']">Hypervisors</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/management']">Management</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/users']">Users</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">
              <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/user-projects']">Users Projects</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/test']">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div *ngIf="loggedIn()" class="dropdown" dropdown>
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" dropdownToggle>
        Welcome <strong>{{ authService.decodedToken?.unique_name | titlecase }}</strong>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu mt-3" *dropdownMenu>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-primary" [routerLink]="['/projects/', 
          authService.decodedToken?.nameid ]"><i class="fa fa-archive">&nbsp;My Projects</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item text-danger" (click)="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign- 
        out">&nbsp;Logout</i></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <form *ngIf="!loggedIn()" #loginForm="ngForm" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o text-primary" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" required 
        [(ngModel)]="model.username" />
      </div>

      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <div class="input-group-text">
            <i class="fa fa-unlock text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" required type="password"
          [(ngModel)]="model.password" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" type="submit" (click)="loginAsUser()" class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0">
          <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;User
        </button>
        <button [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" type="submit" (click)="login()" class="btn btn-success 
           my-2 my-sm-0">
          <i class="fa fa-user-secret" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Admin
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</nav>
```

My guard looks like:

```
 canActivate(): boolean {
    if(this.authService.loggedIn()) {
      return true
    }    

    this.alertify.error('You have no access to see this page!!!');
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: You may need to save it in LocalStorage else the data will always be lost. Not Angular, any other libraries store data in variable forever. You need cookie or LocalStorage to save datas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh the page it does not persist variable values, you need to store either in local storage or cookie.

A simple way to solve this is to use this lib:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-cookies

To install this library, run:

```
npm install ng2-cookies
```

Component

```
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies';

ngOnInit() {
    this.model.isAdmin = Cookie.get('isAdmin');
}

login() {
    this.authService.login(this.model).subscribe(next => {
      Cookie.set('isAdmin', 'true');
      this.alertify.success('Logged in as Admin')
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error)
    }, () => {
      this.router.navigate(['/projects'])
    })
}
```

you can use ngx-cookie-service also

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service

Answer (score 1):

You will have to store your **Auth_Token** in **localhost/indexDB/SessionStorage** and then inside your route guard check if that token is valid or not.

**This way your app will not require authentication until your token is valid**.

Use this npm module to achieve this : [enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt)

Comment: I setup all jwt both backend and for frontend and it works fine. I am storing my jwt in localStorage. But I am loosing not jwt token but isAdmin boolean value. My question is how to don't loose isAdmin after refreshing. So it is not problem with jwt cause it works even after refreshing

Comment: You would have to add this login in AuthGuard CanActivate Method. Check if token present in storage is valid then return true else return false and navigate to login screen

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the auth service API call with **ngoninit** of the components and get the isAdmin flag. That way when u refresh everytime ngOnInit will get involved and u ll get that flag.

```
ngOnInit(){   this.authService.login(this.model).subscribe(next => {
    this.model.isAdmin = true;
 });
}
```

Comment: when I put my code inside ngOnInit i got exception from interceptor --- Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Ok.. I get your problem now. U have two user logins separately and u are already storing the token in localstorage which makes it easy. You can set this admin flag in your service itself within the token and decode the token to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable in localStorage upon successful login, like

```
isloggedIn(authUser) {
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${this.apiUrl}/api/users/login`, {user: authUser})
      .do(res => this.setSession(res.user))
      .shareReplay();
  }

  private setSession = (authResult) => {
    localStorage.setItem('TOKEN', authResult.token);
    localStorage.setItem('loggedUser', 'y');

    this._router.navigate(['dashboard'])
  };
```

Next time when you enter any component, check

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('loggedUser')){
      this._router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
```

this will authenticate user without calling API again. just get key from LocalStorage.